# Running Selenium Tests in Parallel

Tags: testing, selenium, junit, parallel-processing

I have selenium test that takes 1 minute to complete . If I want to run this 1000 times I have to wait 16 hours . Is there any way I can run 5 tests in parallel so that it can be done in 3 hours ? I have generated a JUnit test scrip and tried to run in with multiple threads but they end up using the same Firefox window .  I don't want to run this on grid cause running 5 Firefox window is not that resource intensive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using below logic you can run your junit cases in parallel.

```
Class[] cls={test1.class,test2.class,test3.class,test4.class};
JUnitCore.runClasses(new ParallelComputer(true,false),cls);
```

In above method first parameter of ParallelComputer() indicates classes and second one is for methods. Here I'm running classes in parallel but not methods.

ParallelComputer Class documentation

http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/experimental/ParallelComputer.html

Comment: Will they each launch a new browser window thought ? Cause with threading I ended up one browser window and each test overwriting previous running test.

Comment: Yes. It will launch multiple browsers. Just give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example 
http://mycila.googlecode.com/svn/sandbox/src/main/java/com/mycila/sandbox/junit/runner/
The file to launch is MySuite.java. Works well for me.